Is @wiris/mathtype-tinymce7 going to come for angular?
We are shifting from ck-editor to tiny mce. We are using tiny mce 7. Sometimes wiris is throwing Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initParsed')Error. My editor is initialized, before setting content I checking whether my editor is present and then I am setting content still. enter image description here. I found a similar issue that says it could be due to mismatch of versions. TinyMce fail while executing setContent So I think maybe this would be solved in wiris version 7.
When I comment wiris it is working fine.
